# Problems while handling the WM_NCCALCSIZE message

Tags: c++, windows

I’m currently developing a Qt gui application with controls on the titlebar, to do this my program deals with the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message and to guarantee a window without rounded corners my program calls the `SetWindowRgn` WinAPI.

Everything works as expected, except for the following issue:

If I change the title of my window(always), change my program icon(always) or call the system menu(sometimes) the native titlebar is drawn over my custom extended frame.

What I’ve tried:

I tried to remove the `WS_BORDER` window flag and it solves this problem, however it’s causes another problem: when the DWM is enabled, my window loses the minimize animation. 
I’ve tried to do this on a Qt window and on a native Win32 window. This problem happens on both cases.

My Question:

Why the native titlebar is drawn over my custom extended frame in that cases and how can I prevent that?

Examples images:

My window before change the title: (expected)

[image]

After the change of the title: (not expected)

[image]

My code: (most relevant parts)

```
bool MainWindow::winEvent(MSG *message, long *result)
{
    switch (message->message)
    {
    case WM_NCCALCSIZE: //Change the client area size
    case WM_NCACTIVATE: //Solve a problem with the borders drawing over my window
        return true;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return QMainWindow::winEvent(message, result);
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*)
{
    HWND hWnd = (HWND)winId();
    HRGN region;

    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);
    int w = rect.right - rect.left;
    int h = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    region = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, w, h);

    SetWindowRgn(hWnd, region, TRUE);
}
```

**Update:**

Based on @Raymond Chen reply I've changed my code to the following:(in order to draw the non client area)

```
bool MainWindow::winEvent(MSG *message, long *result)
{
    switch (message->message)
    {
    case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
    {
        int cx = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZEFRAME);
        int cy = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSIZEFRAME);

        RECT *clientRect = &(reinterpret_cast<NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS*>(message->lParam))->rgrc[0];
        clientRect->left     += (cx);
        clientRect->top      += (0);
        clientRect->right    -= (cx);
        clientRect->bottom   -= (cy);
        return true;
    }
    case WM_NCACTIVATE:
        return true;
    case WM_NCPAINT:
    {
        HWND hWnd = message->hwnd;
        HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(hWnd);
        RECT rect;
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);
        int w = rect.right - rect.left;
        int h = rect.bottom - rect.top;
        RECT r;
        r.top = 0;
        r.left = 0;
        r.bottom = h;
        r.right = w;
        HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0));
        FillRect(hdc, &r, brush);
        DeleteObject(brush);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

        *result = 0;
        return true;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }

    return QMainWindow::winEvent(message, result);
}
```

And here is the result:(the native title bar continues over my custom frame while changing the title)

[image]

Comment: You need to handle WM_NCPAINT too. The default handler paints the standard caption.

Comment: Tried to return `true` to the `WM_NCPAINT` message. The problem persists.

Comment: @user2014561 Do you also set `result` to 0? According to the `WM_NCPAINT` documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145212(v=vs.85).aspx) you must: "An application returns zero if it processes this message."

Comment: @Nik Bougalis: Tried in addition to return `true` to the `WM_NCPAINT` message, pass `*result = 0;`. The problem persists.

Comment: Umm, you need to paint your non-client area too. That's kind of the point of the WM_NCPAINT message.

Comment: Problem is, when you send the WM_SETTEXT message, either explicitly, or via a call to SetWindowText, the DefWindowProc _also_ fires off a part of the code it also calls in response to WM_NCPAINT. To get around this, you can handle calls to WM_GETTEXT and WM_SETTEXT yourself, ensuring that your own code is called to redraw the title-bar. A really good source when doing windows stuff like this is the Wine sources for the GDI functions, as used to run win32 programs under linux. Start here: https://github.com/mirrors/wine/blob/master/dlls/user32/defwnd.c (see line 956 - default WM_SETTEXT action)